# Checking if a value falls within a range which excludes a certain value (label) in several columns

Tags: r, range, apply

I have a dataset in the form below:

```
structure(list(ID = 1:10, Text1 = c(5L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 67L, 
800L, 5L, 9L, 2L), Text2 = c(800L, 800L, 2L, NA, 14L, 3L, 70L, 
6L, 9L, 1L), Text3 = c(3L, 88L, 800L, NA, 4L, NA, 7L, 5L, 7L, 
800L), Text4 = c(1L, 6L, 12L, 1L, 6L, 800L, 1L, NA, 8L, 2L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))


> data
   ID Text1 Text2 Text3 Text4
1   1     5   800     3     1
2   2     8   800    88     6
3   3     3     2   800    12
4   4     1    NA    NA     1
5   5     3    14     4     6
6   6    67     3    NA   800
7   7   800    70     7     1
8   8     5     6     5    NA
9   9     9     9     7     8
10 10     2     1   800     2
```

I want to check the values in each `Text` column. The accepted range of values is from `1` to `10` (**IMPORTANT: the range should also accept ALL decimal numbers in the range, such as 2.3, 3.5, etc.**). But there is also number `800` which is a special label that is **also accepted**.

**OUTPUT**: I want to have the `ID` of the cells that do not satisfy the above condition.

**What is the fastest way to do this for an extremely large dataset (about 5 million rows)?**

I have tried to do this with `with` and `sapply` but I have not been successful:

```
with(data, (Text1 <= 10 & Text1 >= 1) | Text1 == 800)
```

This works well on one column. But I cannot understand how to get the `ID`s and apply the same function to each column.

```
apply(data, grep(pattern = "Text", names(data)), 
    function(x){with(x, (x <= 10 & x >= 1) | x == 800)})
```

This also does not work.

Comment: BTW, where is decimal numbers in your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

```
check_fun <- function(x) {
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  which(!(x <= 10 & x >= 1) | !(x == 800) == FALSE)
}
res <- lapply(data[ , paste0("Text", 1:4)], check_fun) # like akrun, this could be a result
unlist(lapply(seq_along(res), function(x) paste(res[[x]], x + 1, sep = ","))) 
# or with indices, <row,column>
```

Answer (score 0):

If we need to check for each column, loop through the columns of interest (`lapply`, ), use the comparison operators to get the logical vector

```
lst <- lapply(data[-1], function(x) (x >= 0 & x <= 10 & !is.na(x)) | x %in% 800)
```

It is not clear about the expected output.  If we want to remove rows that doesn't have the values in the range

```
data[Reduce(`&`, lst),, drop = FALSE]
```

Or to get only the 'ID's

```
data$ID[Reduce(`&`, lst)]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data %>%
   mutate_at(vars(-ID), funs((. >= 1 & . <= 10 & !is.na(.)) | . %in% 800)) %>%
   reduce(`&`) %>%
   filter(data, .)
```

Comment: @rohuhodoso  Okay, then I can change it to `>` and `<`